# Create dynamic method on function

Tags: javascript

How can I dynamically add a method (method? subfunction?) to a function?
I want something like the below code to work:

```
function myobj(params){

  this.addFunction=function(name,func){
    // add dynamic function to myobj
  }

  return this;
}


params={};
myobj(params);
myobj().addFunction("foo",function(){return "bar";});
myobj().foo();
```

Comment: You should either use `new myobj()` or create a new object in the `myob` function and return that. Do not use `myobj()` with `return this` - that modifies the global object. Always put `"use strict";` before your code.

Comment: You should not call `myobj` repeatedly in this example. Call it once to create an object, then call `.addFunction()` and `.foo()` on that same object every time.

Comment: Hint: `this.addFunction=function(…){…}` does add a method named `addFunction` to the object `this`.

Comment: `this[name] = func;` is what you're looking for, but there are other problems that @Bergi has pointed out.

Comment: And if you want the method to work for all `myobj` instances, you should be using a prototype instead of modifying `this`.

Comment: @Barmar If the method should work for all instances, `addFunction` shouldn't be an instance method either

Comment: True, but it will work either way.

Comment: thank you both, but why do i have to use new and whats wrong with repeatedly calling myobj?